# Dropdown Ipywidgets for a particular dataset

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I have a dataset 'unique_words_df' with three columns "postal code", word_count" and 'unique_word'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IRmH.png)

I want to create a dropdown ipy-widget using the "postal_code" as the dropdown and then I want to plot a count-plot with 'unique_word' on the x-axis. Can anyone give an idea. I tried but it is not working. Error shown is shown below. But the temp data frame looks fine to me.

```
def count_plotter(col = 'postal_code'):
temp = unique_words_df.groupby(col)
sns.countplot(x='unique_word', data=temp)
return temp

col_selector =  widgets.Dropdown(
    options=list(unique_words_df['postal_code'].unique()),
    value='32822',
    description='PINCODE')

interact(count_plotter, col = col_selector)
```

Error:

````
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/interaction.py in update(self, *args)
    254                     value = widget.get_interact_value()
    255                     self.kwargs[widget._kwarg] = value
--> 256                 self.result = self.f(**self.kwargs)
    257                 show_inline_matplotlib_plots()
    258                 if self.auto_display and self.result is not None:

<ipython-input-41-b7e91f1f6779> in count_plot(col)
      1 def count_plot(col = 'postal_code'):
----> 2     temp = unique_words_df.groupby(col)
      3     sns.countplot(x='unique_word', data=temp)
      4     return temp
      5 col_selector =  widgets.Dropdown(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, dropna)
   6509         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
   6510 
-> 6511         return DataFrameGroupBy(
   6512             obj=self,
   6513             keys=by,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in __init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, mutated, dropna)
    523             from pandas.core.groupby.grouper import get_grouper
    524 
--> 525             grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
    526                 obj,
    527                 keys,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate, dropna)
    779                 in_axis, name, level, gpr = False, None, gpr, None
    780             else:
--> 781                 raise KeyError(gpr)
    782         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
    783             # Add key to exclusions

KeyError: '32822'

Out[41]:
<function __main__.count_plot(col='postal_code')>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your code is telling you the answer. You have asked for the `value` to be `All`, but you have added `ALL` as the only other option. The first is title case, and the second is upper case. Set `value='ALL'` should work.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected it. But it does not work still. KeyError: 'All' But the dropdown widget appears.

Comment: There is probably no value 'All' in your `postal_code` column, hence the KeyError. You need to handle the case where you choose `All` specifically in your `count_plotter` function. Either that or use the `SelectMultiple` widget.

Comment: No there is some problem in the first paragraph of the code. I have removed 'All'.

Comment: Post your whole code again, plus the full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks. I will do so. The error pointer is pointing towards the "temp" data frame.

Comment: If you `print(col)` as the first line of your `count_plotter` function you will see the issue. You are trying to groupby a column called '32822', which doesn't exist.